3 checkbox java tree, node selection & checkboxes separate?
Everything is resolved now. Thanks to all who read my question.
Final copy:
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.tree.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Enumeration;

public class CheckBoxTreeExample extends JFrame {

private JTree tree;

public CheckBoxTreeExample() {
    super("CheckBox Tree Example");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    tree = createTree();
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(tree);
    scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 400));
    add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    tree.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(TreeSelectionModel.DISCONTIGUOUS_TREE_SELECTION);

    setSize(350, 450);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setVisible(true);
}

private JTree createTree() {
    DefaultMutableTreeNode root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(new NodeData("Root Node"));

    DefaultMutableTreeNode container1 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(new NodeData("Container 1"));
    DefaultMutableTreeNode container2 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(new NodeData("Container 2"));
    root.add(container1);
    root.add(container2);

    container1.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(new NodeData("Child 1")));
    container1.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(new NodeData("Child 2")));
    container2.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(new NodeData("Child 3")));
    container2.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(new NodeData("Child 4")));

    DefaultTreeModel model = new DefaultTreeModel(root);
    tree = new JTree(model);
    tree.setRowHeight(20);
    tree.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(TreeSelectionModel.DISCONTIGUOUS_TREE_SELECTION);

    tree.setCellRenderer(new CheckBoxNodeRenderer());
    tree.addMouseListener(new NodeSelectionListener(tree));

    for (int i = 0; i < tree.getRowCount(); i++) {
        tree.expandRow(i);
    }

    return tree;
}


private void leftClickLogic(DefaultMutableTreeNode node) {
    // Clear all visual selections
    tree.clearSelection();

    // Recursively uncheck all nodes starting from the root
    DefaultMutableTreeNode root = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) tree.getModel().getRoot();
    clearAllSelections(root);

    // Refresh the tree UI to show updated states
    tree.repaint();
    System.out.println("Left-click logic executed on node: " + node);
}

// Helper method to clear selection states for all nodes in the tree
private void clearAllSelections(DefaultMutableTreeNode node) {
    NodeData nodeData = (NodeData) node.getUserObject();
    if (nodeData != null) {
        // Set all checkboxes states to false
        nodeData.setCheckbox1State(false);
        nodeData.checkbox2State = false;
        nodeData.checkbox3State = false;
    }

    // Recursively apply this to all children
    Enumeration<?> children = node.children();
    while (children.hasMoreElements()) {
        DefaultMutableTreeNode childNode = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) children.nextElement();
        clearAllSelections(childNode);
    }
}




// Helper method to select or deselect only the internal node
private void toggleNodeOnly(DefaultMutableTreeNode node, boolean isSelected) {
    TreePath path = new TreePath(node.getPath());
    if (isSelected) {
        tree.getSelectionModel().addSelectionPath(path);
    } else {
        tree.getSelectionModel().removeSelectionPath(path);
    }
    NodeData nodeData = (NodeData) node.getUserObject();
    nodeData.setCheckbox1State(isSelected);
}

// Helper method to select or deselect the internal node and all its children
private void toggleNodeAndChildren(DefaultMutableTreeNode node, boolean isSelected) {
    toggleNodeOnly(node, isSelected);

    Enumeration<?> children = node.children();
    while (children.hasMoreElements()) {
        DefaultMutableTreeNode childNode = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) children.nextElement();
        toggleNodeOnly(childNode, isSelected);
        if (!childNode.isLeaf()) {
            toggleNodeAndChildren(childNode, isSelected);  // Recursively apply to descendants
        }
    }
}

private void checkAndUncheckParentIfNeeded(DefaultMutableTreeNode node) {
    // Logic to check or uncheck the parent based on child node state
    DefaultMutableTreeNode parentNode = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) node.getParent();
    if (parentNode != null) {
        boolean allChildrenChecked = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < parentNode.getChildCount(); i++) {
            DefaultMutableTreeNode childNode = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) parentNode.getChildAt(i);
            NodeData childData = (NodeData) childNode.getUserObject();
            if (!childData.isCheckbox1State()) {
                allChildrenChecked = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        NodeData parentData = (NodeData) parentNode.getUserObject();
        parentData.setCheckbox1State(allChildrenChecked);  // Update parent Checkbox 1 state based on children
    }
}


// Helper methods to get and set the node state



private void setNodeSelection(DefaultMutableTreeNode node, boolean isSelected) {
    NodeData data = (NodeData) node.getUserObject();
    if (data != null) {
        data.setCheckbox1State(isSelected);
    }
}



public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(CheckBoxTreeExample::new);
}

private static class CheckBoxNodeRenderer extends DefaultTreeCellRenderer {
    @Override
    public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent(JTree tree, Object value, boolean selected,
                                                  boolean expanded, boolean leaf, int row, boolean hasFocus) {
        Component renderer = super.getTreeCellRendererComponent(tree, value, selected, expanded, leaf, row, hasFocus);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, 0, 0));
        JCheckBox checkBox1 = new JCheckBox();
        JCheckBox checkBox2 = new JCheckBox();
        JCheckBox checkBox3 = new JCheckBox();

        if (value instanceof DefaultMutableTreeNode) {
            DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) value;
            Object userObject = node.getUserObject();

            if (userObject instanceof NodeData) {
                NodeData data = (NodeData) userObject;
                checkBox1.setSelected(data.isCheckbox1State());
                checkBox2.setSelected(data.isCheckbox2State());
                checkBox3.setSelected(data.isCheckbox3State());
            }
        }

        panel.add(checkBox1);
        panel.add(checkBox2);
        panel.add(checkBox3);
        panel.add(renderer);
        return panel;
    }
}
class NodeSelectionListener extends MouseAdapter {
    private JTree tree;

    public NodeSelectionListener(JTree tree) {
        this.tree = tree;
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        if (!e.isControlDown()) {
            leftClickLogic(null);  // Call the method to deselect everything
            return;  // Exit early to ensure no other actions are processed
        }
        TreePath path = tree.getPathForLocation(e.getX(), e.getY());

        if (path == null) return;

        DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) path.getLastPathComponent();
        if (!(node.getUserObject() instanceof NodeData)) return;

        NodeData nodeData = (NodeData) node.getUserObject();
        int level = path.getPathCount() - 1;
        int checkboxWidth = 20, gapWidth = 5, totalCheckboxWidth = 3 * checkboxWidth + 2 * gapWidth;
        int indentation = level * 20;

        if (e.getX() >= indentation && e.getX() < indentation + totalCheckboxWidth) {
            if (e.getX() < indentation + checkboxWidth + gapWidth) {
                // Checkbox 1 logic
                if (e.isControlDown()) {
                    System.out.println("Ctrl-click on Checkbox 1");
                    handleCheckbox1Click(node, true);  // Passing 'true' for Ctrl-click
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Regular click on Checkbox 1");
                    handleCheckbox1Click(node, false);  // Passing 'false' for regular click
                }
            } else if (e.getX() >= indentation + checkboxWidth + gapWidth && e.getX() < indentation + 2 * (checkboxWidth + gapWidth)) {
                // Checkbox 2 logic
                if (e.isControlDown()) {
                    System.out.println("Ctrl-click on Checkbox 2: cycling state");
                    cycleCheckbox2State(node, nodeData);
                } else {
                    toggleCheckbox2(node, nodeData);
                    System.out.println("Checkbox 2 toggled to: " + nodeData.isCheckbox2State());
                }
                restoreCheckbox1State(node, nodeData);
            } else if (e.getX() >= indentation + 2 * (checkboxWidth + gapWidth) && e.getX() < indentation + 3 * (checkboxWidth + gapWidth)) {
                // Checkbox 3 logic
                if (e.isControlDown()) {
                    System.out.println("Ctrl-click on Checkbox 3: cycling state");
                    cycleCheckbox3State(node, nodeData);
                } else {
                    toggleCheckbox3(node, nodeData);
                    System.out.println("Checkbox 3 toggled to: " + nodeData.isCheckbox3State());
                }
                restoreCheckbox1State(node, nodeData);
            }
        } else {
            // Standard node click logic for general node selection (non-checkbox area)
            if (e.isControlDown()) {
                if (!nodeData.isCheckbox1State() && !nodeData.isCheckbox2State() && !nodeData.isCheckbox3State()) {
                    nodeData.setCheckbox1State(true);  // Only affect the clicked node
                    tree.addSelectionPath(path);
                    System.out.println("Ctrl-click on child node when nothing is selected: Node added to selection");
                } else {
                    nodeData.setCheckbox1State(false);  // Or toggle it off
                    System.out.println("Ctrl-click to toggle child node state");
                }
            } else {
                leftClickLogic(node); // Handle general left-click behavior for node
            }
        }

        tree.repaint();
    }

    // Toggle Checkbox 2 state for the node only
    private void toggleCheckbox2(DefaultMutableTreeNode node, NodeData nodeData) {
        nodeData.setCheckbox2State(!nodeData.isCheckbox2State());
    }

    // Toggle Checkbox 3 state for the node only
    private void toggleCheckbox3(DefaultMutableTreeNode node, NodeData nodeData) {
        nodeData.setCheckbox3State(!nodeData.isCheckbox3State());
    }

    // Cycle Checkbox 2 states with Ctrl-click for internal nodes and propagate to children
    private void cycleCheckbox2State(DefaultMutableTreeNode node, NodeData nodeData) {
        if (!nodeData.isCheckbox2State()) {
            nodeData.setCheckbox2State(true);
        } else if (nodeData.isCheckbox2State() && !areAllChildrenCheckbox2Selected(node)) {
            updateCheckbox2Children(node, true);
            nodeData.setCheckbox2State(true);
        } else {
            updateCheckbox2Children(node, false);
            nodeData.setCheckbox2State(false);
        }
        tree.repaint();
    }

    // Cycle Checkbox 3 states with Ctrl-click for internal nodes and propagate to children
    private void cycleCheckbox3State(DefaultMutableTreeNode node, NodeData nodeData) {
        if (!nodeData.isCheckbox3State()) {
            nodeData.setCheckbox3State(true);
        } else if (nodeData.isCheckbox3State() && !areAllChildrenCheckbox3Selected(node)) {
            updateCheckbox3Children(node, true);
            nodeData.setCheckbox3State(true);
        } else {
            updateCheckbox3Children(node, false);
            nodeData.setCheckbox3State(false);
        }
        tree.repaint();
    }

    // Update Checkbox 2 state for all child nodes
    private void updateCheckbox2Children(DefaultMutableTreeNode node, boolean state) {
        Enumeration<TreeNode> children = node.children();
        while (children.hasMoreElements()) {
            DefaultMutableTreeNode child = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) children.nextElement();
            if (child.getUserObject() instanceof NodeData) {
                ((NodeData) child.getUserObject()).setCheckbox2State(state);
            }
        }
    }

    // Update Checkbox 3 state for all child nodes
    private void updateCheckbox3Children(DefaultMutableTreeNode node, boolean state) {
        Enumeration<TreeNode> children = node.children();
        while (children.hasMoreElements()) {
            DefaultMutableTreeNode child = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) children.nextElement();
            if (child.getUserObject() instanceof NodeData) {
                ((NodeData) child.getUserObject()).setCheckbox3State(state);
            }
        }
    }

    // Restore Checkbox 1 state if it was previously selected
    private void restoreCheckbox1State(DefaultMutableTreeNode node, NodeData nodeData) {
        if (nodeData.isCheckbox1State()) {
            // Re-select Checkbox 1 to maintain its state
            nodeData.setCheckbox1State(true);
            tree.addSelectionPath(new TreePath(node.getPath()));  // Ensure the path is selected
        }
    }

    // Check if all children have Checkbox 2 selected
    private boolean areAllChildrenCheckbox2Selected(DefaultMutableTreeNode node) {
        Enumeration<TreeNode> children = node.children();
        while (children.hasMoreElements()) {
            DefaultMutableTreeNode child = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) children.nextElement();
            if (child.getUserObject() instanceof NodeData) {
                if (!((NodeData) child.getUserObject()).isCheckbox2State()) return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    // Check if all children have Checkbox 3 selected
    private boolean areAllChildrenCheckbox3Selected(DefaultMutableTreeNode node) {
        Enumeration<TreeNode> children = node.children();
        while (children.hasMoreElements()) {
            DefaultMutableTreeNode child = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) children.nextElement();
            if (child.getUserObject() instanceof NodeData) {
                if (!((NodeData) child.getUserObject()).isCheckbox3State()) return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }


    public void handleCheckbox1Click(DefaultMutableTreeNode node, boolean isCtrlClick) {
        NodeData nodeData = (NodeData) node.getUserObject();
        if (nodeData == null) return;

        // Get the current state of the node (based on the checkbox1State)
        int currentState = getNodeState(node);
        System.out.println("Current state before click: " + currentState); // Debugging

        if (node.isLeaf()) {
            // Leaf node: Toggle only the checkbox and selection for this node
            toggleCheckboxAndSelection(node, !nodeData.isCheckbox1State());
        } else {
            // Internal node: Cycle through the states
            if (isCtrlClick) {
                System.out.println("Ctrl-click detected: Toggling state");

                switch (currentState) {
                    case 0: // Deselect all
                        // Transition to state 1: Select internal node only
                        setNodeState(node, 1);
                        toggleCheckboxAndSelection(node, true);  // Select internal node only
                        break;
                    case 1: // Select internal node only
                        // Transition to state 2: Select internal node and all children
                        setNodeState(node, 2);
                        toggleCheckboxAndSelection(node, true);  // Select internal node
                        toggleChildrenSelection(node, true);     // Select all children
                        break;
                    case 2: // Select internal node and all children
                        // Transition to state 0: Deselect internal node and all children
                        setNodeState(node, 0);
                        toggleCheckboxAndSelection(node, false); // Deselect internal node
                        toggleChildrenSelection(node, false);    // Deselect all children
                        break;
                }
            } else {
                // Regular click (without Ctrl): Cycle through the states
                switch (currentState) {
                    case 0: // Deselect all
                        // Transition to state 1: Select internal node only
                        setNodeState(node, 1);
                        toggleCheckboxAndSelection(node, true);  // Select internal node only
                        break;
                    case 1: // Select internal node only
                        // Transition to state 2: Select internal node and all children
                        setNodeState(node, 2);
                        toggleCheckboxAndSelection(node, true);  // Select internal node
                        toggleChildrenSelection(node, true);     // Select all children
                        break;
                    case 2: // Select internal node and all children
                        // Transition to state 0: Deselect internal node and all children
                        setNodeState(node, 0);
                        toggleCheckboxAndSelection(node, false); // Deselect internal node
                        toggleChildrenSelection(node, false);    // Deselect all children
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println("State after click: " + getNodeState(node)); // Debugging
        tree.repaint();
    }

    // Helper method to toggle the checkbox state and selection for a node
    private void toggleCheckboxAndSelection(DefaultMutableTreeNode node, boolean isSelected) {
        NodeData data = (NodeData) node.getUserObject();
        data.setCheckbox1State(isSelected); // Toggle Checkbox 1 state

        // If Checkbox 1 is unchecked, also uncheck Checkbox 2 and 3
        if (!isSelected) {
            data.setCheckbox2State(false);  // Uncheck Checkbox 2
            data.setCheckbox3State(false);  // Uncheck Checkbox 3
        }

        TreePath path = new TreePath(node.getPath());
        if (isSelected) {
            tree.getSelectionModel().addSelectionPath(path);  // Add to selection if selected
        } else {
            tree.getSelectionModel().removeSelectionPath(path);  // Remove from selection if deselected
        }
    }

    private void toggleChildrenSelection(DefaultMutableTreeNode node, boolean isSelected) {
        Enumeration<?> children = node.children();
        while (children.hasMoreElements()) {
            DefaultMutableTreeNode child = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) children.nextElement();
            toggleCheckboxAndSelection(child, isSelected); // Apply to all children
        }
    }
    private int getNodeState(DefaultMutableTreeNode node) {
        NodeData data = (NodeData) node.getUserObject();
        if (data == null) return 0;  // Default state (deselected)
        if (data.isCheckbox1State()) {
            // If Checkbox 1 is selected, check if it has children selected
            return hasChildrenSelected(node) ? 2 : 1; // State 1 or State 2
        }
        return 0; // State 0: Deselect all
    }

    // Helper method to check if any children are selected
    private boolean hasChildrenSelected(DefaultMutableTreeNode node) {
        Enumeration<?> children = node.children();
        while (children.hasMoreElements()) {
            DefaultMutableTreeNode child = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) children.nextElement();
            NodeData childData = (NodeData) child.getUserObject();
            if (childData != null && childData.isCheckbox1State()) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false; // No children are selected
    }

    // Helper method to set the state of the node
    private void setNodeState(DefaultMutableTreeNode node, int state) {
        NodeData data = (NodeData) node.getUserObject();
        if (data == null) return;

        switch (state) {
            case 0: // Deselect all
                data.setCheckbox1State(false);
                break;
            case 1: // Select internal node only
                data.setCheckbox1State(true);
                break;
            case 2: // Select internal node and all children
                data.setCheckbox1State(true);
                break;
        }
    }



    public void handleCheckbox1Click(DefaultMutableTreeNode node) {
        NodeData nodeData = (NodeData) node.getUserObject();
        if (nodeData == null) return;

        System.out.println("Current state before click: " + getNodeState(node)); // Debugging: Print current state

        if (node.isLeaf()) {
            // Handle click on a child node
            toggleCheckboxAndSelection(node, !nodeData.isCheckbox1State()); // Toggle child node state
            checkAndUncheckParentIfNeeded(node); // Check parent if needed based on child toggle
        } else {
            // Handle click on an internal node (cycle through three states)
            int currentState = getNodeState(node);
            System.out.println("State before change: " + currentState); // Debugging: State before change
            switch (currentState) {
                case 0:
                    // State 1: Select only the internal node
                    toggleCheckboxAndSelection(node, true);
                    setNodeState(node, 1);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    // State 2: Select the internal node and all children
                    toggleCheckboxAndSelection(node, true);
                    toggleChildrenSelection(node, true);
                    setNodeState(node, 2);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    // State 0: Deselect the internal node and all children
                    toggleCheckboxAndSelection(node, false);
                    toggleChildrenSelection(node, false);
                    setNodeState(node, 0);
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Unexpected state encountered");
                    break;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("State after click: " + getNodeState(node)); // Debugging: Print state after click
        tree.repaint();
    }

    private void leftClickLogic(DefaultMutableTreeNode node) {
        // Clear all selections in the tree
        tree.clearSelection();

        // Reset the state of each node's checkboxes
        Enumeration<TreeNode> nodes = ((DefaultMutableTreeNode) tree.getModel().getRoot()).preorderEnumeration();
        while (nodes.hasMoreElements()) {
            DefaultMutableTreeNode currentNode = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) nodes.nextElement();
            if (currentNode.getUserObject() instanceof NodeData) {
                NodeData data = (NodeData) currentNode.getUserObject();
                data.setCheckbox1State(false);
                data.setCheckbox2State(false);
                data.setCheckbox3State(false);
            }
        }

        // Refresh the tree display
        tree.repaint();

        System.out.println("Left-click anywhere: All nodes and checkboxes deselected.");
    }

}















public static class NodeData {
    public int state;
    private final String text;
    private boolean checkbox1State;
    private boolean checkbox2State;
    private boolean checkbox3State;

    public NodeData(String text) {
        this.text = text;
        this.state = 0;
    }
    public boolean getCheckbox1State() {
        return checkbox1State;
    }
    public boolean isCheckbox1State() { return checkbox1State; }

    public void setCheckbox1State(boolean state) {
        System.out.println("setCheckbox1State() called with state: " + state);
        this.checkbox1State = state; }

    public boolean isCheckbox2State() { return checkbox2State; }

    public void toggleCheckbox2State() { this.checkbox2State = !checkbox2State; }

    public boolean isCheckbox3State() { return checkbox3State; }

    public void toggleCheckbox3State() { this.checkbox3State = !checkbox3State; }

    @Override
    public String toString() { return text; }

    public void setCheckbox2State(boolean state) { this.checkbox2State = state; }
    public void setCheckbox3State(boolean state) { this.checkbox3State = state; }

}
}


Old post below.


This is a new update to my original question for the java 8 tree I'm working on. I figured out synchronizing the 1st checkbox with the node selection. I still am failing in getting the 2nd and 3rd checkboxes to checkmark separately from each other and the 1st checkbox, while also not interfering with the node selection state controlled by the 1st checkbox.


Here is the new code:

https://pastebin.com/4TDPnhAX
First Post Below:


I'm using java 8 to create a tree application with 3 checkboxes beside each node. I'm trying but failing to synchronize the 1st checkbox with the node selection. It's supposed to select when the checkbox is checked. When unchecked, the node should also unselect.


Another problem I'm not sure how to fix is the 2nd and 3rd checkboxes should checkmark separately, while not interfering with the node selection state.


The 2nd and 3rd checkboxes later on will apply their own separate logic each on a node previously selected by the 1st checkbox. The 1st checkbox being unchecked means that the 2nd or 3rd checkbox doesn't affect the node if clicked.


Here is what I have so far:

PasteBin-Java-Tree
